# Captive portal popup works on Mac but not iOS (6 or 7)

Tags: captivenetwork

I have a Raspberry Pi running Hostapd, Dnsmasq and Lighttpd so that when a user connects to the AP on the Pi, they get redirected to a .local url no matter what they enter in a browser.  This works fine on any system.

I've found numerous threads regarding captive portal issues in iOS7, but I have the opposite problem - I don't want to bypass the splash page.  I need it to appear consistently.  When I connect to the AP from a Mac (10.8.5), the popup window with the page hosted by the Pi comes right up in a mini-browser window, but not on iOS 6 or 7.

What is the Captive Network Assistant doing differently on each of these systems?  Is there something I need to do in lighttpd.conf to enable it?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm on same boat. How do you redirect the requests to your raspberry portal? I'm also using raspberry, I used iptables to alter the destination ip of the packets and forward it to raspi web portal. It also works on any other OS but not ios